# gulp dev says Local gulp not found when its clearly installed

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, npm-install

It has been 8 hours since I started looking into this issue and so far I haven't made any progress.

Every time i run `gulp dev` I get the error

`Local gulp not found in 
Try running: npm install gulp`

I have run `npm install gulp`, `npm install gulp-cli`, both variantes (with `-g` and without). I have tried to search online and I have found some people saying that I need run `npm link gulp` but every time I run that command I get the following  in the console:

[image: npm link gulp error]

And here the process of trying to installing gulp[image]

I dont really know what to do more.

I should say I'm running windows 10 on parallels destop. On my mac os gulp is running fine.

Comment: Please try installing gulp globally so that it is available throughout your system. Try this: npm install -g gulp or place your /node_modules/.bin on your global environment path.

Comment: @RaviGehlot I have done that already, it still says local not found

Comment: Try to run just gulp instead of "gulp dev". If gulp runs, then do what @Ghostrydr mentioned. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Apparently when using parallels desktop you are not able to run gulp from a shared folder, my project was running from `\\Mac\Home\Documents\Git\Development\Wigo4it\GIWI\Components` . What I did was moving the project from my shared folder to my `C:/` inside the windows VM. And now it works. Just had some troubles with write permissions but that is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed gulp local to your project you're going to need to run it via an npm script. Add something like the following to your `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp dev"
 }
```

Then run it like this

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: As I said, it runs on my mac without adding anything. On windows (running through parallels desktop) it keeps saying Local not found

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't installed Gulp globally on your Mac. What do you get if you run `npm ls -g --depth 0`.

Comment: `├── @angular/cli@1.7.4
├── gulp@4.0.0-alpha.3 (github:gulpjs/gulp#71c094a51c7972d26f557899ddecab0210ef3776)
└── npm@5.6.0`

Answer (score 0):

better off using something like `npx` which'll resolve it in your project, if not then in your `$PATH`.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx

as a result you'd run `npx gulp`